# how to use (RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding) in android

Tags: java, android, encryption, rsa

About a year ago, I wrote an application for Android and used a class in it RSA In this class, there was the following code snippet and the application worked

```
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding")
```

But when I re-entered the application code, I did not open the new encrypted information to change the private key until I changed the above code line to the following code line.

```
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(keyFactory.getAlgorithm());
```

The problem is that if I replace the above code snippet in class RSA it is no longer possible to open previously encrypted information (with the same keys as before).
And I see the following error

```
javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: error:04000084:RSA routines:OPENSSL_internal:PKCS_DECODING_ERROR
```

RSA decryption

```
public static byte[] decryptByPrivateKey(byte[] data, String key)
            throws Exception {

        byte[] keyBytes = decryptBASE64(key);


        PKCS8EncodedKeySpec pkcs8KeySpec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(keyBytes);
        KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance(KEY_ALGORITHM);
        Key privateKey = keyFactory.generatePrivate(pkcs8KeySpec);

        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");
        
        // Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(keyFactory.getAlgorithm());


        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, privateKey);

        return cipher.doFinal(data);
    }
```

Comment: Did you ever try to debug = print out the value given by keyFactory.getAlgorithm? On my machine it's "RSA" and that's not the same algorithm as "RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding". Always use a full qualifier to the algorithm you are using.

Comment: Your question title should be amended, as `keyFactory.getAlgorithm()` doesn't seem to implement PKCS#1 padding, and that's what you're having problems with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RSA key pairs can be used within different RSA based schemes, such as PKCS#1 and OAEP padding for encryption, and PKCS#1 and PSS padding for signing. However, there is only one key pair generation possible, which is simply denoted `"RSA"`.

If only `"RSA"` is used as input string it will use the defaults set for the specific cryptography provider, which is - in this case - the first provider that implements RSA using keys in software. Apparently that's different on Android from PKCS#1 padding (assuming that you still use the original list of providers, of course). One stupid thing in Java is that you cannot programmatically find out which defaults *are* used; `getAlgorithm()` ususally just returns the string you've provided earlier. The only thing you can do is to get the provider using `getProvider()` and then lookup the defaults...

I would never go for any defaults (except for `SecureRandom` defaults) as it is unspecified which defaults will be used for Java. Always specify the algorithm in full; your earlier string was fine.

Comment: you could edit the result of `System.out.println(getProvider())` in the question together with your runtime environment - Android API level and such, in the hope that somebody knows or can find out the defaults...

Comment: Does Swift have the same issues where one should specify the provider instead of taking the default?

Comment: It doesn't seem so, as the Apple API requires [explicit identifiers](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/seckeyalgorithm) for each. Before the fanboys cry "victory": this is Apple, so they don't really specify what protocol e.g. `rsaEncryptionOAEPSHA1AESGCM` follows, so their API is not a good example of a generic crypto library. That basically means that they are compatible with Apple only (gosh)...

Answer (score 0):

My function

```
 private fun getEncryptCodeWord(publicKey:String, codeWord:String):String{
        try{
            val publicBytes = Base64.decode(publicKey, Base64.NO_WRAP)
            val keySpec = X509EncodedKeySpec(publicBytes)
            val keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA")
            val pubKey = keyFactory.generatePublic(keySpec)
            val encryptCodeWord = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding")
                .apply { init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, pubKey) }
                .doFinal(codeWord.toByteArray())
            return Base64.encodeToString(encryptCodeWord, Base64.NO_WRAP)
        }
        catch (ex:Exception){
            Crash.recordException(ex)
            Crash.setKey("error_get_encrypt_code_word",ex.message)
        }
        return codeWord
    }
```

and for RSA/ECB/OAEPWithSHA-256AndMGF1Padding

```
private fun getEncryptCodeWord(publicKey:String,codeWord:String):String{
    try{
        val publicBytes = Base64.decode(publicKey, Base64.NO_WRAP)
        val keySpec = X509EncodedKeySpec(publicBytes)
        val keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA")
        val pubKey = keyFactory.generatePublic(keySpec)
        val sp = OAEPParameterSpec("SHA-256", "MGF1", MGF1ParameterSpec("SHA-1"), PSource.PSpecified.DEFAULT)
        val encrypt = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/OAEPWithSHA-256AndMGF1Padding")
        encrypt.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, pubKey, sp)
        val encryptCodeWord = encrypt.doFinal(codeWord.toByteArray())
        return Base64.encodeToString(encryptCodeWord, Base64.NO_WRAP)
    }
    catch (ex:Exception){
        Crash.recordException(ex)
        Crash.setKey("error_get_encrypt_code_word",ex.message)
    }
    return codeWord
}
```